# Memcpy from an array is only working 1/20 instances correctly?

Tags: c++, memcpy

I am coping an item to an array of structures... then copy that element from the array of structures to a char array... but only every 1/20 is working ??

```
typedef struct{
    double dTime;
    char cMessage[11];
} typeCanMessage;
```

---

```
typeCanMessage *m_cmMessageCB = new typeCanMessage[1000]; //max size can be the CB


memcpy(m_cmMessageCB + *m_posWrite * sizeof(typeCanMessage), &m_cmMessageWrite, sizeof(typeCanMessage));


// WORKS
//memcpy(cStr, &m_cmMessageWrite.cMessage, 11);             

// FAILS: every 1/20 works
memcpy(cStr, m_cmMessageCB->cMessage + *m_posWrite * sizeof(typeCanMessage), 11);
```

Comment: In the second one, do you actually want to be multiplying by the size of the struct?

Comment: So, you have a structure that is one double and 11 chars. That is likely 8 bytes + 11 bytes + 1-padbyte. Hmmm....

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm pretty sure there are a few cases where it could pad 5 bytes, but I think I know what you're getting at ;)

Comment: I have no idea what your last memcpy is supposed to do - why are you using `m_cmMessageCB->cMessage + ...` - what is after the message at `*m_posWrite * sizeof TypeCanMessage`?

Comment: You should almost never use `memcpy` in C++; prefer the safe alternatives. (And `typedef struct { ... } X;` is written `struct X { ... };` in C++.)

Comment: @AlanStokes I completely agree, but other than the tag, *nothing* in this code exhibits anything remotely related to C++. Ugh.

Comment: The expression `m_cmMessageCB[*m_posWrite].cMessage` makes more sense than the address arithmetic you currently use.

Comment: @Blastfurnace... had done that and yields same result

Comment: for completeness what is m_iNBufferLength? Also what is the definition of cStr and how are you defining failure are you getting garbage or a segfault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic scales the number by the size of the type of the pointer. `m_cmMessageCB->cMessage` is a char* pointer, and `sizeof(char)` is one by definition, so multiplying it by the size of the structure should give the right value. On the other hand `m_cmMessageCB + *m_posWrite` will already multiply `*m_posWrite` by `sizeof(typeCanMessage)`, so doing it again will throw off the calculation entirely. I'm surprised it's even working once in every 20 times.

Comment: memcpy(cStr, (m_cmMessageCB + *m_posWrite)->cMessage, 12);  yields same result as:  memcpy(cStr, m_cmMessageCB->cMessage + *m_posWrite * sizeof(typeCanMessage), 12); //fails: every 20

Comment: @jdl I'm saying the problem is not when you're reading the result, it's when you're filling the array in the first place.

Comment: *m_posWrite increments by one for each new message. So I need to scale by the size of the struct.  I tried without it and there is nothing written.

Comment: @jdl, no you don't! Pointer arithmetic automatically scales it for you, based on `sizeof(*pointer)`.

Comment: when I looked at the sizeof typeCanMessage... the result is 20

Comment: @jdl: If you just use `m_cmMessageCB[*m_posWrite]` it will correctly do the address arithmetic for you. If that doesn't work then you have a different problem.

Comment: @jdl see for example http://ideone.com/ZniCuT. Notice that the pointers are *not* 1 apart.

Comment: @jdl the arithmetic is performed on the pointer *before* it's converted to `void*`. `memcpy` might not care about the element size but `+` sure does.

Comment: as this was just a snippet I neglected to add code that incremented *m_posWrite prior to writing to the second array... thx, as the pointer arithmetic played out later in the code.